# How to use while loop in shell to read from one file and redirect to another

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a file named `unimplemented.txt` which looks like :

```
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx,./TDM/SDH.xls
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1plus1-xxx,./TDM/SDH.xls
```

How do I use while loop to read above file and generate an output file at `/TDM/SDH_check.xls` which contains

```
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx
```

I tried doing this but it goes into infinite loop

```
while IFS="," read dummy casename tpname < "unimplemented.txt"
do
    echo "$casename" > basename $tpname|sed -e 's/\..\+$//'
done
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do to the data? Remove everything from the first comma to end of line? Is that last part of the input the name of the output file, or is the output file constant? (You have `./TDM/SDH.xls` in the input data, but  `SDH_check.xls` as the output file name, so there's that extra `_check` too

Comment: Yes I want to generate a file in the same path without disturbing the existing file so added _check and also need only data until "," in the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there's several problem in your script:

1. Why do you `read dummy casename tpname` ? In this line, read is waiting for 3 fields, but you have and want only 2.
2. When you write `echo "$casename" > basename $tpname|sed -e 's/\..\+$//'`, it does:

   1. echo `$casename` into `basename` (and not `$basename`).
   2. apply the `sed` substitution to the output of echo... which is nothing.
3. You use `>` which will overwrite upon each call to `echo`. To append, use `>>`.

Below looks correct for me, but not sure if it is what you want:

```
gcolangelo@NEO-L196:/tmp/pouet$ cat unimplemented.txt 
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx,./TDM/SDH.xls
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1plus1-xxx,./TDM/SDH.xls
verify-sdh-t2-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx,./TDM/SDG.xls
verify-sdh-t2-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1plus1-xxx,./TDM/SDG.xls
gcolangelo@NEO-L196:/tmp/pouet$ cat unimplemented.txt | while IFS=',' read casename tpname ; do echo "$casename"|sed -e 's/\..\+$//' >> $tpname ; done
gcolangelo@NEO-L196:/tmp/pouet$ cat TDM/SDH.xls 
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx
verify-sdh-t1-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1plus1-xxx
gcolangelo@NEO-L196:/tmp/pouet$ cat TDM/SDG.xls 
verify-sdh-t2-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1for1-xxx
verify-sdh-t2-satop-traffic-over-mpls-1plus1-xxx
```

Comment: This is what I want but not in TDM/SDH.xls (this is an existing file and do not want to edit it), hence generating new file  TDM/SDH_check.xls in same path.

Comment: So adjust for your need dude.

Comment: Yeah done it. Thanks for the help.